# Trigger cronjobs on Fibase Firestore update

Tags: firebase, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a scheduling system to run a firebase cloud function after 60 minutes from a specific event in the database. After some lectures I know that firebase has not a built in schedule system. Indeed, what I have to do is to schedule an http request when a specific document in firestore is updated. Someone recommends me https://cron-job.org/en/, anyone knows if with this service I can schedule automatically some http requests when a document in firestore is updated?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to have a http request when a document in firestore updated you may need firestore trigger function initialized instead cron-job. something like ;

```
exports.makeHttpRequest = functions.firestore
  .document('myCollection/myDocument').onUpdate((event) => {
    setTimeout( ()=> {
        var cronJobUrl = "https//:www..."; // Set the url you want to make a http request
        windows.open(cronJobUrl);
    },60000*60)  // to fire this function after 60 min. 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that a firebase cloud function does not support such a long timeout, it will be stopped way before.

Comment: Ok. You are right, I didn't consider it for a min. But  If you want exactly after 60min, then I do not know for now, but if you say min 60 min. possible after 60-120 min then there is another solution. If suits I will try to explain

Comment: this 60-120 min. may narrow gap. upon your wish. ie 60-75 min. ( But you will need to consider calling a cloud functions frequency.